# How do I set Postgres DB Schema for all Golang Gorm ORM query statements?

Tags: postgresql, go, schema, go-gorm

I have many different schemas in a single instance of a Postgres DB. I am creating a simple GoLang service that needs to connect to one or more schemas.

In configuring the DB connection there seems to be no way to point to any specific schema, nor on the Model itself. How can I add {schema}.Model to my queries?

```
main() {
  db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=elliot password=ness dbname=goodfellas sslmode=disable")
  defer db.Close()

  db.CreateTable(&Gangsta{})
}
type Gangsta struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}
```

I would like for this particular table to be created in Postgres DB 'goodfellas' in the 'players' schema, making a statement like

```
 CREATE TABLE "players.Gangstas" ("id" serial,"created_at" timestamp with time zone,"updated_at" timestamp with time zone,"deleted_at" timestamp with time zone,"name" text , PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

Same goes for all other SQL queries...

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "players.Gangstas"` will create a table in the default schema named `players.Gangstas`. If you want to create a table in a different schema you need to use `CREATE TABLE "players"."Gangstas"`

Comment: If you want to always do that, you can change the search_path for the user `alter user elliot set search_path = 'players, public'`;

Comment: this isn't relevant to the configuration of the gorm ORM

Comment: The search_path is irrelevant from the client

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - get that...but the question is whether or not I can have Gorm prepend the schema to the table within each query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the only option seems to be via DB configuration, so I found the query 'SET search_path TO players' is scoped to the current DB connection, so it'll do for now!